# jquery if else condition for css api

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I have the below jquery statement

```
$(this).('span.section1').css('background','url("images/accordion_closed_left.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent');
```

How do I write a if else statement for the css condition. What I mean is if the background image is accordion_closed_left.png then `<do this>` or else `<do this>`.

just to be precise `<do this>` are blocks of statement.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is going to be slow and horrendous to maintian. Use classes instead.

Comment: This is surely not correct: `$(this).('span.section1')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a *css class* instead and then call jQuery's `.hasClass()` method on it:

**css**:

```
.closed {
    background: url("images/accordion_closed_left.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

**js**:

```
var $target = $(this).find('span.section1');

if( $target.hasClass( 'closed' ) ) {
    $target.removeClass( 'closed' );
} 
else {
    $target.addClass( 'closed' );
}
```

Comment: +1! This is by far the most elegant solution. Classes combine styling and state.

Comment: a bit more elegant: $(this).find("span.section1").toggleClass("closed");

Comment: @roberkules: pretty much depends on the usecase. By just toggling classes you have no chance to do other stuff, which is probably what you want when using it as *state*.

Comment: right. toggleClass would only be used if no extra logic is needed.

Answer (score 0):

How to write this in `jQuery` with 'guides' as a class name....

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function guideMenu()
{
    if (document.getElementById('guides').style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById('guides').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('guides').style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

To naively answer your question:

```
if ($(this).('span.section1').css('background').match('|/accordion_closed_left\.png"|')) {

}
else {

}
```

However I support jAndy's answer, [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) is the way to go!