# jQuery script which works in Chrome, but does not work in FireFox and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I wrote a script that works wonders in Chrome, but it does not work in Opera and Firefox. I'm new in JavaScript. Prompt in what could be wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $("#question_tab").hover(function() {
        if ($("#question").css("left") == "100%")
            $("#question").css("margin-left", "-50px");
    }, function() {
        if ($("#question").css("left") == "100%")
            $("#question").css("margin-left", "-38px");
    });

    $("#question_tab").click(function() {
        if ($("#question").css("left") == "100%") {
            $("#question").animate({
                marginLeft: "-380px",
                left: "50%"
            });
        } else {
            $("#question").animate({
                marginLeft: "-38px",
                left: "100%"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I think problem is in checking - `if ($("#question").css("left") == "100%")`

HTML, JS and CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/HjS9z/4/

Problem with sliding question form.

Comment: What part of the script doesn't work in FF or Opera? Any JS errors?

Comment: try to use `$(document).width()` instead of `"100%"` and `($(document).width() / 2)` instead of "50%"

Comment: could you post your html as well. Its hard to replicate the issue without it.

Comment: Posting a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging would be your best friend here (easiest way since you are new to JS could be to use alert() or it would be better to either set break points or use console.log()

** for other readers I know alert() is not preferred, I'm simply giving options for those who are new to JS and debugging

You would see that for instance: `$("#question").css("left")` value equals '100%' in chrome, but in firefox for instance that value is defined in pixels (837px for instance).  So the reason your code fails in other browsers is because your "IF" statement never resolves to true (match).

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to use classes for your positioning, and then your jQuery logic could simply swap the classes out for your click/hover events.

EX: .qHoverOn .qHoverOff .qShow .qHide etc...  This way you simply specify where you want your items positioned instead of your attempt to map to 100% or -38px etc...

Comment: no problem @arturtr, please mark my answer as accepted as it seems to have helped you.  It encourages others to help you in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

If found solving of my problem here: [jquery if else condition for css api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104124/jquery-if-else-condition-for-css-api)

I add class "hidden" for hidden form. Working code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#question_tab").hover(function() {
        if ($("#question").hasClass("hidden"))
            $("#question").css("margin-left", "-47px");
    }, function() {
        if ($("#question").hasClass("hidden"))
            $("#question").css("margin-left", "-36px");
    });

    $("#question_tab").click(function() {
        if ($("#question").hasClass("hidden")) {
            $("#question").animate({
                marginLeft: "-380px",
                left: "50%"
            });
            $("#question").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $("#question").animate({
                marginLeft: "-36px",
                left: "100%"
            });
            $("#question").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
```